# I want my image be all over the screen - also include when I click F12

Tags: html, css

I want my image be all over the screen - also while I click f12 or smaller screen

my html `<img src="assets/photos/body_building.jpg" class="backgroundImage">`

my css

```
.backgroundImage {
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I want all of that picture and don't cut nothing from it.

Thanks for help!

edit - some pictures

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hard work I actually fix it .
I share it :-)

HTML `<img src="/assets/photos/body_building.jpg" class="backgroundImage">`

CSS

```
.backgroundImage {
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Work perfectly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With this code-snipped it should work. You have to include the image via `background: url(IMAGENAME);`

```
.backgroundImage {
    background: url("1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: 100% 100%; /*first for width, second for height*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}
```

The page content must be written at `<div class="backgroundImage">`

I hope it will solves your problem

Comment: unfortunately no , and  i use height: auto; no netter only width must be width: 100%; for full image i will upload some pictures

Comment: but if you don‘t have height: 100% you will never have a picture over the full screen as far as i know. for half page you need height: 50%. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp

Comment: when i change it as height: 100% i have bigger page but when i roll down there isn't some picture only in start screen

Comment: So you want a background image that is fixed and the content in the foreground is scrollable?

Comment: yes , it need to be all the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try { width: 100vw ; height: 100vh } not sure if that's what you need?

Comment: still do the same problem